# Why Event log is NOT shown in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, events, logs

I want to see Event logs in UI. And for this, I use following code in JavaScript :

```
var EnergyEvent = Coursetro.setEnergyEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
               EnergyEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
  }

})
```

> **What is missed in my JavaScript code ?**

You can see full code of my contract and JavaScript code in bellow:

> solidity code :

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import './SafeMath.sol';
import './Ownable.sol';

contract Weechain is Ownable{

  using SafeMath for uint256;

  uint256 public energyTotalSupply;
  uint256 public powerTotalSupply;

  struct Device {
    uint256 energyValue;
    uint256 powerValue;
  }
  mapping(address => Device) amount;

  event setEnergyEvent(address indexed device, uint256 energy); 
  event setPowerEvent(address indexed device, uint256 power);
  event setPayloadEvent(uint256 indexed SQN, string payload);

  // Constructor
  function Weechain() {

    energyTotalSupply = 0;
    powerTotalSupply = 0;

    amount[owner].energyValue = energyTotalSupply;
    amount[owner].powerValue = powerTotalSupply;
  }

  function amountOfenergy(address dev) constant returns (uint256 energy) {
    return amount[dev].energyValue;
  }
  function amountOfpower(address dev) constant returns (uint256 power) {
    return amount[dev].powerValue;
  }

  function setPayload(uint256 SQN, string payload) public returns (bool) {

    emit setPayloadEvent(SQN, payload);

    return true;
  }

  function setEnergy(address dev, uint256 energy) public returns(bool) {
    require(dev != address(0));

    amount[dev].energyValue = amount[dev].energyValue.add(energy);
    energyTotalSupply = energyTotalSupply.add(energy);

    emit setEnergyEvent(dev, energy);

    return true;
}

    function setPower(address dev, uint256 power) public returns (bool) {
    require(dev != address(0));

    amount[dev].powerValue = amount[dev].powerValue.add(power);
    powerTotalSupply = powerTotalSupply.add(power);

    emit setPowerEvent(dev, power);

    return true;
  }

}
```

> Javascript and HTML code :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Weechain Smart Contract</title>



    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
</style>

<style>
.input {
    background-color: #373E43;
    color: black;
}
</style>

<style>
.header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #373E43;
    color: white;
}
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>

<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #373E43; color: white;}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #373E43; color: white;}
</style>

<style>
.output {
background-color: #373E43; 
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="w3-container">

    <div class="header">
  <h1>Weechain</h1>
</div>

        <!-- <p>Output: <span id="owner"></span> 
        </p> -->
        <div class="output">
        <p id="Output" >  </p>
        </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="input">
  <div class="column">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Device Address</label>
        <input id="Address" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Energy</label>
        <input id="Energy" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <button id="buttonSet" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Set Energy Value</button>

        <button id="buttonGet" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Get Energy Balance</button>

   </div>
   <div class="column">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Device Address</label>
        <input id="AddressPower" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Power</label>
        <input id="Power" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <button id="buttonSetPower" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Set Power Value</button>

        <button id="buttonGetPower" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Get Power Balance</button>

   </div>
   <div class="column">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Sequence Number</label>
        <input id="SQN" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Payload</label>
        <input id="Payload" class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%"> 

        <button id="buttonSetPayload" class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large">Set Payload Value</button>

   </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
          <h2 class="sub-header">Energy Transactions</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Transaction Hash</th>
                  <th>Device Address</th>
                  <th>Energy Value</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="transactions">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <h2 class="sub-header">Power Transactions</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Transaction Hash</th>
                  <th>Device Address</th>
                  <th>Power Value</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="transactionsPower">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <h2 class="sub-header">Payload Transactions</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Transaction Hash</th>
                  <th>Payload</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="transactionsPayload">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
           web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
       } else {
           web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
       }

       //this.watchEvents = this.watchEvents.bind(this)

       web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
/*
       var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_fName","type":"string"},{"name":"_age","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setInstructor","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getInstructor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);
*/
    var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"energyTotalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"}],"name":"amountOfenergy","outputs":[{"name":"energy","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"powerTotalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"},{"name":"energy","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setEnergy","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"SQN","type":"uint256"},{"name":"payload","type":"string"}],"name":"setPayload","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"}],"name":"amountOfpower","outputs":[{"name":"power","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"},{"name":"power","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPower","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"device","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"energy","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setEnergyEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"device","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"power","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPowerEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"SQN","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"payload","type":"string"}],"name":"setPayloadEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_by","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"ChangementOwnership","type":"event"}]);

       var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x8db88aaa4990408dfe41d6c77a76a09cba95d982');
/*
       var utils = require("./utils.js");
var _ = require("lodash");
var Promise = require("bluebird");

module.exports = {
    assertEvent: function(contract, filter) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var event = contract[filter.event]();
            event.watch();
            event.get((error, logs) => {
                var log = _.filter(logs, filter);
                if (log) {
                    resolve(log);
                } else {
                    throw Error("Failed to find filtered event for " + filter.event);
                }
            });
            event.stopWatching();
        });
    }
}
*/



/*
var instructorEvent = Coursetro.setEnergyEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
instructorEvent.watch(function(error, result){
    alert(1);
});
*/

/*
var event = testing.event_res(function(error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result.args);
    else
        console.log(error);
});
*/

 var EnergyEvent = Coursetro.setEnergyEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
               EnergyEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
  }
  // append details of result.args to UI
})
/*
var instructorEvent = Coursetro.setEnergyEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});   
instructorEvent.watch(function(error, EventLogs){
if (!error) {
    alert(1);
    console.log('Event Logs:' + EventLogs);
    } else
                console.log('Event Logs error:' + error);

});
*/

       $("#buttonGet").click(function() {
       Coursetro.amountOfenergy($("#Address").val(), function(error, result) {
           if (!error) {
               $("#Output").html('Energy value of device with address ' + $("#Address").val() + ' equals '+ result.toString());//+' ('+result[1]+')');
               console.log('Energy value of device with address \"' + $("#Address").val() + '" equals "'+ result.toString() + '"');

               var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x5337d09cc54c1ec80970b7c74881f01cbf5653293873d54617b64fad21f6fb68');
               console.log(' tx hash: ' + receipt.toString());
               /*console.log("address\tfrom\t\tto\tamount\tblockHash\tblockNumber\tevent\tlogIndex\ttransactionHash\ttransactionIndex");*/
           } else
                console.log(error);
       });

       });
/*
       $("#buttonSet").click(function() {
           //Coursetro.setPayload($("#name").val(), $("#age").val());
           Coursetro.setEnergy($("#Address").val(), $("#Energy").val());
           //Coursetro.setPayload($("#name").val());
       });
*/
       $("#buttonSet").click(function() {
    var estd_gas = Coursetro.setEnergy.estimateGas($("#Address").val(), $("#Energy").val());
    console.log(estd_gas);
    var params = {
        gas: Math.round(estd_gas * 1.25),
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    };

    Coursetro.setEnergy.sendTransaction($("#Address").val(), $("#Energy").val(), params, function(error, TxHash) {
           if (!error) {

               $("#Output").html('Transaction Hash in Hexadecimal:'+ TxHash.toString());//+' ('+TxHash[1]+')');
               $('#transactions').append('<tr><td>' + TxHash.toString() + '</td><td>' + $("#Address").val() + '</td><td>' + $("#Energy").val() + '</td></tr>')
               console.log(TxHash.toString());




               //var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xc7be46f83e4c382995512357b99f97796b1e902c60d2667a068b062776a00dd4');
               //var receipt2 = web3.toAscii(TxHash.input);
               //console.log(receipt.toString());

               //Coursetro.setEnergyEvent({},{fromBlock: 0,toBlock: 'latest'}).watch((error, event) => {})

               /*var EnergyEvent = Coursetro.setEnergyEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
               EnergyEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return;
  }
  // append details of result.args to UI
})*/



               //console.log(receipt2.toString());
           } else
                console.log(error);
       });
});

////


///////////////////////



 $("#buttonSetPower").click(function() {
    var estd_gas = Coursetro.setPower.estimateGas($("#Address").val(), $("#Power").val());
    console.log(estd_gas);
    var params = {
        gas: Math.round(estd_gas * 1.25),
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    };
    Coursetro.setPower.sendTransaction($("#Address").val(), $("#Power").val(), params, function(error, TxHash) {
           if (!error) {
               $("#Output").html('Transaction Hash in Hexadecimal:'+ TxHash.toString());//+' ('+TxHash[1]+')');
               $('#transactionsPower').append('<tr><td>' + TxHash.toString() + '</td><td>' + $("#Address").val() + '</td><td>' + $("#Power").val() + '</td></tr>')
               console.log(TxHash.toString());
               //var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xc7be46f83e4c382995512357b99f97796b1e902c60d2667a068b062776a00dd4');
               //var receipt2 = web3.toAscii(TxHash.input);
               console.log(receipt.toString());
               //console.log(receipt2.toString());
           } else
                console.log(error);
       });
});



$("#buttonGetPower").click(function() {
       Coursetro.amountOfpower($("#Address").val(), function(error, result) {
           if (!error) {
               $("#Output").html('Power value of device with address ' + $("#Address").val() + ' equals '+ result.toString());//+' ('+result[1]+')');
               console.log('Power value of device with address \"' + $("#Address").val() + '" equals "'+ result.toString() + '"');

               //var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x5337d09cc54c1ec80970b7c74881f01cbf5653293873d54617b64fad21f6fb68');
               console.log(' tx hash: ' + receipt.toString());
               /*console.log("address\tfrom\t\tto\tamount\tblockHash\tblockNumber\tevent\tlogIndex\ttransactionHash\ttransactionIndex");*/
           } else
                console.log(error);
       });

       });







////////////////////   






       $("#buttonSetPayload").click(function() {
    var estd_gas = Coursetro.setPayload.estimateGas($("#SQN").val(), $("#Payload").val());
    console.log(estd_gas);
    var params = {
        gas: Math.round(estd_gas * 1.25),
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    };
    Coursetro.setPayload.sendTransaction($("#SQN").val(), $("#Payload").val(), params, function(error, TxHash) {
           if (!error) {
               $("#Output").html('Transaction Hash in Hexadecimal:'+ TxHash.toString());//+' ('+TxHash[1]+')');
               $('#transactionsPayload').append('<tr><td>' + TxHash.toString() + '</td><td>' + $("#Payload").val() + '</td></tr>')
               console.log(TxHash.toString());
               //var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('0xc7be46f83e4c382995512357b99f97796b1e902c60d2667a068b062776a00dd4');
               //var receipt2 = web3.toAscii(TxHash.input);
               console.log(receipt.toString());
               //console.log(receipt2.toString());
           } else
                console.log(error);
       });
});



////////////////


    // TODO: trigger event when vote is counted, not when component renders







    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note 1 : I used this tutorial :** https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e

**Update :** I changed my JavaScript code regarding to comment of User Ismael. However, I do not see still the event logs.

Comment: You are setting your watch event after the transaction is sent and you have to do it before.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you. I moved the code before click event for setEnergy transaction, however I do not still see the loge in UI. there is still some thing wrong in Javascript code ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to develop a web application that interacts with a smart contract (send transaction, pull events, etc.). I really recommend you to use [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) (to compile/deploy/test smart contracts) and [truffle-contract library](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract) (to interact from a web page).

**Smart contract**

Step 1: Install Truffle

```
$ npm install -g truffle
```

Step 2: Initialise the project

```
$ truffle init
```

Step 3: Add your contract and libraries (openzepellin) in the folder "contract"

```
$contracts$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gjeanmart gjeanmart  515 May 13 17:34 Migrations.sol
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gjeanmart gjeanmart 1010 Oct 26  1985 Ownable.sol
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gjeanmart gjeanmart 1134 Oct 26  1985 SafeMath.sol
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gjeanmart gjeanmart 1646 May 13 18:53 Weechain.sol
```

Step 4: Write a deployment script in the folder "migration"

```
$ vi 1_initial_migration.js
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};


$ vi 2_deploy_contracts.js
var Weechain = artifacts.require("./Weechain.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Weechain)
};
```

Step 5: Write the configuration in "truffle.js"

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Step 6: Deployment

Execute `truffle develop` to run a sandbox Ethereum Blockchain.

```
$ truffle develop
Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:9545/

Accounts:
(0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
(1) 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
(2) 0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef
(3) 0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544
(4) 0x0d1d4e623d10f9fba5db95830f7d3839406c6af2
(5) 0x2932b7a2355d6fecc4b5c0b6bd44cc31df247a2e
(6) 0x2191ef87e392377ec08e7c08eb105ef5448eced5
(7) 0x0f4f2ac550a1b4e2280d04c21cea7ebd822934b5
(8) 0x6330a553fc93768f612722bb8c2ec78ac90b3bbc
(9) 0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de

Private Keys:
(0) c87509a1c067bbde78beb793e6fa76530b6382a4c0241e5e4a9ec0a0f44dc0d3
(1) ae6ae8e5ccbfb04590405997ee2d52d2b330726137b875053c36d94e974d162f
(2) 0dbbe8e4ae425a6d2687f1a7e3ba17bc98c673636790f1b8ad91193c05875ef1
(3) c88b703fb08cbea894b6aeff5a544fb92e78a18e19814cd85da83b71f772aa6c
(4) 388c684f0ba1ef5017716adb5d21a053ea8e90277d0868337519f97bede61418
(5) 659cbb0e2411a44db63778987b1e22153c086a95eb6b18bdf89de078917abc63
(6) 82d052c865f5763aad42add438569276c00d3d88a2d062d36b2bae914d58b8c8
(7) aa3680d5d48a8283413f7a108367c7299ca73f553735860a87b08f39395618b7
(8) 0f62d96d6675f32685bbdb8ac13cda7c23436f63efbb9d07700d8669ff12b7c4
(9) 8d5366123cb560bb606379f90a0bfd4769eecc0557f1b362dcae9012b548b1e5

Mnemonic: candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat

⚠️  Important ⚠️  : This mnemonic was created for you by Truffle. It is not secure.
Ensure you do not use it on production blockchains, or else you risk losing funds.
```

Then run `migrate` to deploy your smart contract on this blockchain.

```
truffle(develop)> migrate
Compiling ./contracts/Ownable.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/SafeMath.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Weechain.sol...
Compiling Ownable.sol...
Compiling SafeMath.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/home/gjeanmart/workspace/personal/stackexchange/48396-why-event-log-is-not-shown-in-html-page/contracts/Weechain.sol:24:3: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
  function Weechain() {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
,/home/gjeanmart/workspace/personal/stackexchange/48396-why-event-log-is-not-shown-in-html-page/contracts/Weechain.sol:33:3: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
  function amountOfenergy(address dev) constant returns (uint256 energy) {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
,/home/gjeanmart/workspace/personal/stackexchange/48396-why-event-log-is-not-shown-in-html-page/contracts/Weechain.sol:36:3: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
  function amountOfpower(address dev) constant returns (uint256 power) {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'develop'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0xcb0ccc3f1fbe419b96b95c6ef63e54ac8557061922702e89ae44e1c288508247
  Migrations: 0x8cdaf0cd259887258bc13a92c0a6da92698644c0
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xd7bc86d31bee32fa3988f1c1eabce403a1b5d570340a3a9cdba53a472ee8c956
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying Weechain...
  ... 0x0bd3d3d1534c391abc50a1e3164499e45da9bb49b4501aa9fde3515440d50c7e
  Weechain: 0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xf36163615f41ef7ed8f4a8f192149a0bf633fe1a2398ce001bf44c43dc7bdda0
Saving artifacts...
truffle(develop)>
```

Your smart contract are now deployed on a sandbox blockchain accessible with the RPC endpoint **http://localhost:9545** and the following accounts are created and funded each with 100 ethers (these account can be imported in Metamask for testing)

```
Accounts:
(0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
(1) 0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732
(2) 0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef
(3) 0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544
(4) 0x0d1d4e623d10f9fba5db95830f7d3839406c6af2
(5) 0x2932b7a2355d6fecc4b5c0b6bd44cc31df247a2e
(6) 0x2191ef87e392377ec08e7c08eb105ef5448eced5
(7) 0x0f4f2ac550a1b4e2280d04c21cea7ebd822934b5
(8) 0x6330a553fc93768f612722bb8c2ec78ac90b3bbc
(9) 0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de

Private Keys:
(0) c87509a1c067bbde78beb793e6fa76530b6382a4c0241e5e4a9ec0a0f44dc0d3
(1) ae6ae8e5ccbfb04590405997ee2d52d2b330726137b875053c36d94e974d162f
(2) 0dbbe8e4ae425a6d2687f1a7e3ba17bc98c673636790f1b8ad91193c05875ef1
(3) c88b703fb08cbea894b6aeff5a544fb92e78a18e19814cd85da83b71f772aa6c
(4) 388c684f0ba1ef5017716adb5d21a053ea8e90277d0868337519f97bede61418
(5) 659cbb0e2411a44db63778987b1e22153c086a95eb6b18bdf89de078917abc63
(6) 82d052c865f5763aad42add438569276c00d3d88a2d062d36b2bae914d58b8c8
(7) aa3680d5d48a8283413f7a108367c7299ca73f553735860a87b08f39395618b7
(8) 0f62d96d6675f32685bbdb8ac13cda7c23436f63efbb9d07700d8669ff12b7c4
(9) 8d5366123cb560bb606379f90a0bfd4769eecc0557f1b362dcae9012b548b1e5
```

**Web Application**

Now, the web application, you will see that now, it is very easy and clean to access the smart contract from your webpage.

Step 1: Use nodejs to serve your webapplication. Create a file `serve.js`

```
$ npm i -s connect serve-static truffle-contract
$ vi serve.js
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server running on 8080...');
});
```

Step 2: Run the webserver

```
$ node serve
```

Now your index.html `http://localhost:8080` page is available as well as the Truffle Smart contract artifacts (sort of JSON file containing everything: ABI, Addresses, etc.) `http://localhost:8080/build/contracts/Weechain.json`

Step 3: initialise Web3 and load the contracts

```
  // Load Web3
  console.log("### LOAD WEB3")
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }
  console.log(web3)

  // Default account
  console.log("### DEFAULT ACCOUNT")
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
  console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount)

  // Get Truffle Contract artefact
  console.log("### Get Truffle Contract artefact")
  var Coursetro;
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/build/contracts/Weechain.json", function( data ) {
    console.log(data)

    // Load Contract
    var CoursetroContract = TruffleContract(data);
    CoursetroContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

    // Get contract instance
    CoursetroContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      Coursetro = instance;
      console.log(Coursetro)
    });

  });
```

Step 4: Send transactions and get the events triggered from the receipt

```
  $("#buttonSet").click(function() {
      Coursetro.setEnergy($("#Address").val(), $("#Energy").val()).then(function(receipt) {
        console.log(receipt)
        console.log("Logs trigerred for this transaction:")
        console.log(receipt.logs)
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      });

  });
```

[image]

---

This demonstrates how the Truffle framework (+Ganache) can abstract and simplify most of the complexity of Web3 development in general.
The tutorial you mentioned is good but unfortunately June 2016 sounds a bit old. Blockchain technologies are moving and evolving very quickly !

**[Full code example](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/48396-why-event-log-is-not-shown-in-html-page)**

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer. However, when I open your `HTML` file, I don't get transaction hash. In fact, I created a new folder entitled "`Weechain_truffle_version`" and copied all your files in your `Github`. Then, I open `index.html` file and send a transaction `(ex: setEnergy)` . However, I don't receive `Tx hash` in UI. Should I do some additional thing ? Thanks again.

Comment: In fact, when I run `truffle init` I receive this error : [Error message](https://ibb.co/iMMqJy) Maybe that's the problem, isn't it ? Thank you

Comment: About `truffle init`, I think it's normal because the problem is already initialized if you pull my code.

Comment: About the transaction issue, I had some problems like that in that past with `truffle develop` (new feature). So I generally manually start a sandbox blockchain `ganache-cli -p 9545` (in another console) and run `truffle migrate` instead of `truffle develop` followed by `> migrate`

Comment: Thank you again, but I confused a bit.Please consider I downloaded all your package in your Github in a folder entitled "`Weechain_truffle_version`" [Screen](https://ibb.co/jMnmrJ) in my computer. then, I open a `cmd`. I did `npm install -g truffle`. However, when I run `truffle init` , I receive this error : [Error](https://ibb.co/iMMqJy). Then, I open another `cmd` and run `ganache-cli -p 9545`, fortunately it works and I get this output : [ganache](https://ibb.co/bwCEdy) . I am grateful to you if you could let me know which `commands` should I run with `cmd` respectively. Thx

Comment: Btw,as you can see in this screen shot (https://ibb.co/bwCEdy) after `Listening on localhost:9545` I don't receive any message, is it OK? Thank you again

Comment: When I fix an error, then I receive another error :(  really I don't know what is my mistake .....

Comment: Please reach me on twitter or linkedin. Will try to help you off-chain :-D

Comment: I just created a twitter account and followed you, (`my account: @Siamak75460931`) However, apparently I am not able to send you any message by twitter. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I just found a new thing : when I use `ganache-cli -p 9545` after that in `cmd` I don't receive any thing, but when I use `ganache-cli -p 8545` I receive data (similar when I run `testrpc`) However in this case in the `GUI` I receive this error : https://ibb.co/ciu5Jy But really i don't know what must be modified ? Thanks very much again.